# Is there a more systematic way to fix hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation

I found out that the Czech word „množina“ meaning “a set” is hyphenated „množi-na“ by TeX rather than „mno-ži-na“. What is worse the word „podmnožina“ meaning “a subset” is hyphenated „podm-noži-na“ rather than „pod-mno-ži-na“ which is unacceptable.

Is there any better and more systematic way to fix this hyphenation than using exception list provided by `\hyphenation` command? I mean it is easy to fix the word „množina“, but there are many forms of it in the Czech language: „množina“, „množiny“, „množině“, „množinu“, „množino“, „množinou“, „množin“, „množinám“, „množinách“, „množinami“ for all of which the point is to allow hyphenation „mno-ži“. And to all these forms I should add the corresponding prefixed forms „pod-mno-ži-…“ where the rule is just to hyphenate between the prefix and the root or hyphenate in the root as if the was the sole word. My point is that the list of exceptions multiplicatively grows when fixing just one issue.

As suggested, I'm adding a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \lefthyphenmin=0
    \righthyphenmin=0
    \begin{minipage}{0pt}
        first
        podmnožina
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I noted that if I change IL2 font encoding to T1, the hyphenation works as expected. What does font encoding have to do with hyphenation?

Comment: there may be more than one set of Czech patterns available (there are for English) so you probably need to provide an example document showing how you specified Czech. `\hyphenation` only accepts a full list of words and has no concept of stem or compound words. the `\patterns` command does take a list of patterns, although the TeX algorithm historically has problems with languages making use of compound words as it can only specify potential hyphenation points in a word it can not prioritise breaks at compound word boundaries over breaks within the parts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`, with new version of babel package and new, clear insallation of MikTeX 2.9 distribution under Windows. Is it possible to locate and inspect the used set of patterns?

Comment: again an example document would help as hyphenation is tied to font encoding and the engine you are using (pdftex, xetex) etc. The pattern format isn't particular;y readable but you should have a file something like  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-cs.tex  adjusted for wherever miktex is installed on your machine

Comment: If I have `\usepackage[czech]` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, I get hyphenations `mno-žina` and `pod-mno-žina`. In all the flexed forms of *množina*, the hyphen is always after *mno*; moreover the forms of *podmnožina* are all hyphenated `pod-mno-...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the example.

Comment: @egreg I have also noted it suprisingly works with T1. See edited question.

Comment: The hyphenation patterns used when `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` is found are tailored for a T1-encoded font. As far as I know, IL2 is used with a different setup for Czech than `babel`. Don't worry: T1 has full support for Czech letters.

Comment: @egreg Why is there a connection between hyphenation patterns and font encoding in the first place? I would think there should be no connection at all.

Comment: @user87690 in an ideal world:-) (but not in TeX)

Comment: @user87690 roughly by the time TeX comes to considering hyphenation the incoming list of characters has _already)_ been typeset into a horizontal list in which the character items already denote _font_ positions so (unfortunately) hyphenation patterns have to be adjusted to any font encoding in use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well this is unfortunate. Now I'm starting to think that the right approach to hyphenation in TeX is to include the discretionaries into source file by some kind of preprocessor.

Comment: @user87690 This is, almost, the approach used by CSLaTeX, which indeed uses IL2 encoded fonts. But it has the limitation that only Czech and Slovak are supported. However, the documentation of CSLaTeX says: “CSLaTeX is obsolete, don't use it please; you can use normal LaTeX+Babel or XeLaTeX+polyglossia”.

Comment: @user87690 LuaTeX handles this differently for exactly this reason, but for 'traditional' TeX that's just the way things are.

Comment: @egreg I stared to use IL2 instead of T1 because T1 produces pixelization when zoomed. On the other hand IL2 has this problem I didn't know about. CSLaTeX apparently solves this but isn't univeral and as you say is obsolete. I would think that in this situation either T1 works with no problems or the better hyphenation patterns are encoded for IL2 and there is somewhere a recommendation to use IL2.

Comment: @JosephWright So another reason to migrate to LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @user87690 It's better to add `\usepackage{lmodern}` and use `T1` encoding.

Comment: @user87690 pixelation is a feature of using bitmap fonts, not of the encoding, you should be able to get the fonts you need in scalable type1 format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Czech hyphenation patterns are OK, but you have used bad font encoding.

The CSLaTeX is obsolete, but I try to explain how it works. It reads the Czech and Slovak hyphenation patterns twice: in IL2 encoding and T1 encoding. The appropriate hyphenation pattern is used when one write `\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

When you don't use CSLaTeX, you *cannot* use IL2 encoded fonts for Czech and Slovak because standard LaTeX supports only one hyphenation pattern per language and it uses T1 encoded pattern for Czech and Slovak. (Note: `csplain` is another case, it supports more hyphenation patterns per language but it is probably not subject of your interest).

There are well know bugs in T1 encoded font metrics typically generated by `fontenc` which get fonts unusable in Czech and Slovak (for example `ptmr8t` metric for Times Roman). The bug is in the letters ď and ť. But more than 20 years nobody reported this bug so it seems to be not actulaly used.

On the other hand, nobody was obliged to maintain CSlaTeX and it brings more problems than advantages. Thus I labeled it as obsolete. People at Czech/Slovak TeX list accept this. The result: LaTeX Czech/Slovak users cannot use IL2 encoded font and they can bugreport the T1 encoded metrics.